# How do i find out which user/application deleted/removed System DSN from ODBC

Tags: sybase

We are having weird issue with our ODBC system DSN. With our application automatically system DSN is created but our client claims that after some time system DSN is deleted/removed. We couldnt find any logs for that but we assume that this is deleted/removed by user (client) or their application (domain policy or some restrictions). Could anyone help how to find out above issue?
Our application name is Micros RES 3700 and SQL Anywhere 11 is installed with application which creates system DSN.